# All Unity APKS crash in an Android Phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

I build an android apps about naked 3d display with Unity. I run it in 4 android phones, it runs well. But when I run it in a naked 3d mobile phone, the apps crashed. And all the apps generated with Unity can't run in this phone, even the simplest scene in Unity. But the apps generated by Android Studio, it can run well. It really confused me!

Here is the Log when I run the app in this phone, the phone is PPTV KING 7S.

```
04-13 11:14:18.841 753-1671/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (has extras)} from uid 10040 on display 0
04-13 11:14:18.844 753-1671/? D/ActivityManager: [BMW] insertTaskAtTop fromHome = true lastStack = ActivityStack{8e74335 stackId=0, 1 tasks} this = ActivityStack{21b3d16c stackId=1, 11 tasks} topTask() = TaskRecord{1bd9c12a #6110 A=com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D U=0 sz=0}
04-13 11:14:18.845 753-1671/? D/ActivityManager: [BMW] insertTaskAtTop fromHome = true lastStack = ActivityStack{8e74335 stackId=0, 1 tasks} this = ActivityStack{21b3d16c stackId=1, 12 tasks} topTask() = TaskRecord{256d73f #6127 A=com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D U=0 sz=0}
04-13 11:14:18.853 753-785/? D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is disabled, fakeHwAccelerated = true, HardwareRenderer.sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, HardwareRenderer.sSystemRendererDisabled = false, this = ViewRoot{15248c3c Starting com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D,ident = 12}
04-13 11:14:18.896 753-778/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 10076:com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/u0a150 for activity com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
04-13 11:14:19.187 10076-10076/? D/ViewRootImpl: disable hardware acceleration by APP!!!, this = ViewRoot{a4d2229 com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity,ident = 0}
04-13 11:14:19.229 753-785/? I/WindowManager: Gaining focus: Window{9d23207 u0 com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
04-13 11:14:19.375 753-785/? I/ActivityManager: [AppLaunch] Displayed Displayed com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +517ms
04-13 11:14:19.375 753-785/? D/ActivityManager: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_LaunchTime:com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity:517:984383
04-13 11:14:19.445 753-785/? I/WindowManager: Screen frozen for +522ms due to Window{322db31a u0 Starting com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D}
04-13 11:14:19.534 10076-10100/? I/libGLES: file /storage/sdcard0/.gmax/shared_prefs/com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D.gmaxC do not exit!
04-13 11:14:19.535 10076-10100/? I/libGLES: file /storage/sdcard0/.gmax/shared_prefs/com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D.gmaxE do not exit!
04-13 11:14:21.983 753-2065/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{9d23207 u0 com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
04-13 11:14:21.984 753-773/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D (pid 10076) has died
04-13 11:14:21.984 753-2065/? W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{2f8b3d64 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{9d23207 u0 com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
04-13 11:14:21.984 753-773/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{3ed8675e u0 com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t6127}: app died, no saved state
04-13 11:14:21.994 277-353/? D/SurfaceFlinger:     remove: com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
04-13 11:14:21.995 753-785/? I/WindowManager: Losing focus: Window{9d23207 u0 com.ShanghaiTech.Naked3D/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
```

I think it's not the problem in my Unity program. Anyone has some solution to deal with the problem?

Comment: What Unity version and what Android version? These are important info to provide when you have crashing problems.

Comment: My unity version is 5.3.4 and my android version is andorid 5.1. But this andorid version is customized by the company of mobile phone. I run my program on another company's phone with android 5.1, it works well.

Comment: You just provided the important information I needed.  The problem is not from Unity but from the ROM of the phone. It is likely corrupted or the vendor removed some features from the phone. Unity depends on those feature to run properly. My suggestion for you is to try re-installing the Android ROM version. Also install Unity 5.4 beta and see if Unity fixed it. http://unity3d.com/unity/beta